# What is a more concise way to create these rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We are looking to create a WHERE IN statement in BigQuery Standard SQL and would like to select from a set of values.

We are currently using this code:

```
WHERE IN ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 )
```

Is there a more concise way to write this? If so, how?

Comment: Where what IN, do you have anymore code to share?

Comment: `WHERE IN` is not a construct.  Something needs to go between the `WHERE` and the `IN`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more concise way to write this?

```
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: have this answered your question?